# Why are my AS3 class files running code out of order?

Tags: actionscript-3, class, scope, flash-cs6, document-class

I am currently learning to use separate .as files and classes, but after reading a lot everything seems to work different from what I've read.
I'm posting this question for the purpose of learning, not just to make the code work.
The examples here are tested, simplified recreations of my real project.

My file "MyApp.fla" has 1 frame with a shape as background, the DocumentClass is set to "MyApp".
The library holds a symbol "Page1" of 1 frame with another background shape, with it's class set to "Page1"

MyApp.as:

```
package  {

    trace("1: DocumentClass file, before class");
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class MyApp extends MovieClip {

        trace("2: DocumentClass file, in the class")
        public var setting1:int = 2; //this is a variable which i want to be accesible to other classes, so to the pages being loaded
        private var currentPage:MovieClip; //I wanted to create this var in the constructor, but I'm afraid something will explode again :<

        public function MyApp() {
            trace("3: DocumentClass file, in constructor function");
            currentPage = new Page1;
            addChild(currentPage);
        }
    }

}
```

Page1.as:

```
package  {

    trace("4: Page1 file, before class");
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class Page1 extends MovieClip {

        trace("5: Page1 file, in class, before constructor");


        public function Page1() {
            trace("6: Page1 file, in constructor")
            trace(setting1) //According to everything i read this should work since setting1 is public, but it gives me: "1120 Acces of undefined property setting1" so i commented this out for the output.
            trace(root); 
            trace(stage); //both trace null since i haven't used addChild() yet, but now i dont know how to try to reference my variables through the main timeline.
        }
    }

}
```

Output:

- 5: Page1 file, in class, before constructor
- 4: Page1 file, before class
- 2: DocumentClass file, in the class
- 1: DocumentClass file, before class
- 3: DocumentClass file, in constructor function
- 6: Page1 file, in constructor
- null
- null

While both background shapes display as expected the generated output is completely out of order from what i expected. My main question is: **Why are my traces not ordered 1 -6?**

My next question: **Why can't the Page1() constructor refer to the public var setting1?**, i assume i can work around by passing setting1 as an argument into the Page1() constructor, but I'm avoiding that for learning purposes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

setting1 is a variable in the parent object, not the object you are attempting to call it from. This just wont work.

```
trace(this.parent.setting1);
trace(MovieClip(parent).setting1);
```

Replacing it with ONE of the above should work, as you'd be calling the variable form where it is referenced, which is the parent.

The reason for the order is:

```
5 - the class itself is imported before anything else
4 - while the class loads, it checks for additional imports
2 - after it finished importing all classes, it loads its own class
1 - again, while the class loads it check for imports
3 - after everything is loaded, it's free to run the main function of the class
6 - same as 3, but the child always walks behind the parent
```

Remember in object orientated programming, it needs to load ALL the objects (or classes) before it tries to do anything with them. Imagine if subclass.as had a variable and class.as tried to access it before it loaded.

Hope this helps :). If you need more details feel free to ask, I kinda just summarized each step.

Comment: changing the trace with this.parent gives compile error 1119: Access of possibly undefined property setting1 through a reference with static type flash.display:DisplayObjectContainer. 
I thought my Document class would run as if it's code was on the MainTimeline, or more accurately create a MovieClip in MainTimeline's place and stick the constructor code in it's frame so to speak and run it. 
And i figured my other class would then be instantiated. Now it seems like all the code is being ran once without creating a single instance.

Comment: trace(MovieClip(parent).setting1) gives TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at Page1()
 at MyApp()
I think i understand your explanation about the order the code runs in, it makes sense, though not as much as running in order. I still don't get why my classes cant access public variables. I imagine the instances, as soon as they're created and/or added have no problem accessing public variables from each other, but from what i read i understood variables should be accessible to classes. Was that just wrong?

Comment: Do you mean that instances of a class that extends MovieClip get the vars and functions from their class definition accessible through instancename.variableorfunctionname? just like a library instance with the same vars and functions written in its frame? otherwise i don't get it. Yeah i cant get addChild() to work in the constructor so the example file would be awesome, thanks!

Comment: I figured it out now! if i change the variable to static `public static var settings1` it can be read and changed through the class itself like so `trace(MyApp.setting1)` or `MyApp.setting1=3`. From what i read but didn't test yet i understand it should be accessible as property of instances as well, though the value will always be equal among instance and the class itself, and that suits me fine for my purposes. Thanks for putting me on the right track!